# cloudant apache-spark access design document

Tags: apache-spark, cloudant

The following works for me when I just use the database name:

```
database = 'databasename'

cloudantdata_df = sqlContext.read.format("com.cloudant.spark").\
option("cloudant.host", host).\
option("cloudant.username", username).\
option("cloudant.password", password).\
load(database)

cloudantdata_df.printSchema()
```

However, when I try to load a particular design document and view name using the format like:

```
database = 'databasename/_design/analytics/_view/invBA'
```

I get the following java exception:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o54.load.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Database databasename/_design/analytics/_view/invBA request error: {"error":"method_not_allowed","reason":"Only GET,POST,HEAD allowed"}

at    com.cloudant.spark.common.JsonStoreDataAccess.getQueryResult(JsonStoreDataAccess.scala:176)
at com.cloudant.spark.common.JsonStoreDataAccess.getMany(JsonStoreDataAccess.scala:85)
at com.cloudant.spark.DefaultSource.create(DefaultSource.scala:114)
at com.cloudant.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:100)
at com.cloudant.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

Is there a way to look at a particular design document view name?

Answer (score 0):

In github, there is an example how to load views:https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/blob/master/examples/python/CloudantDF.py#L74

You need to use `view` option.
In your particular case it will be:

```
cloudantdata_df = sqlContext.read.format("com.cloudant.spark").\
option("cloudant.host", host).\
option("cloudant.username", username).\
option("cloudant.password", password).\
option("view","_design/analytics/_view/invBA").load(database)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked.  Some of these things are hard to figure out because there does not seem to be a published api with all of the features.  Do they really expect people to dig through all of the examples to figure out how to do anything besides the very basic?

Comment: @webe3 All API  is in README file https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/blob/master/README.md; there is a section there on configuration: https://github.com/cloudant-labs/spark-cloudant/blob/master/README.md#Configuration-Overview

Comment: gettting an error while load() function.. Please refer for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40886228/cloudant-database-not-connecting-using-spark-python